# Consume WCF Rest Services in WCF Client

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest

I was evaluating a third party WCF Client tool, [WCFStorm](http://wcfstorm.com/wcf/wcfstorm-lite.aspx). The tool looks good but I couldn't confirm whether I can test REST enabled services through this.
Does it work with REST enabled services. What are other better tools to test REST enabled WCF services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats the link I shared which does not mention anything about REST, thats I shared question on SO.

Comment: Sorry - maybe i'm confused. The site's home page (http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx) has a section labeled "REST Service Testing with WcfStorm.Rest". The link goes to the address in my comment. Doesn't this confirm that WCFStorm allows you to test REST enabled services?

Comment: Ohh thanks. That clears my doubt. Actually I did not the REST compatibility page.

Comment: I have answered this question, please refer:-

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19520181/2652827